# How do I get a modal to work within a FlatList in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using Flatlist to render a list of pictures.  I would like to click on an individual picture, which would then render a bigger version of that same picture within a modal.  I can't seem to figure out a way to make sure that the modal opens with a bigger version of the picture I clicked on.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, 
        Image,
        TouchableOpacity,
        Modal,
        Alert,

} from 'react-native';

class TestPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            albums: [],
            modalIsOpen: false,
            selectedAlbum: { album: null }
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('component did mount');
        fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    albums: responseData
                });
            });
    }

    selectAlbumPic() {
        console.log('her is the selectAlbumPic thing');
    }
    pictureOpen(item) {
        console.log('here is your item ', item.title);
        this.setState({ 
                modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen,
                selectedAlbum: { album: item }
            });
            console.log('here is your state after the fuction', this.state.selectedAlbum.album);
    }

    closeModal(item) {
        //console.log('here is your seleected album', this.state.selectedAlbum.album.title);

        // console.log('close modal is being pressed irght now');
        this.setState({
            modalIsOpen: false,
            selectedAlbum: { album: null }
        });
        // console.log('here is the album data ', item.album);
    }
    singleAlbumRender(item) {        
        const pictureUrl = item.image;

        return this.state.selectedAlbum === { album: null } ?

            <View style={styles.singleAlbum}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => { 
                        console.log('hey man');
                        console.log('here is your state', this.state.selectedAlbum);
                        this.pictureOpen(item); 
                    }}
                >
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: `${pictureUrl}` }}
                    style={{
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                    }}

                />
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
            :
            <View style={styles.singleAlbum}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => { 
                        console.log('this is the second batch');
                        this.pictureOpen(item); }}
                >
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: `${pictureUrl}` }}
                    style={{
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                    }}

                />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide"    
                    onRequestClose={() => {}}
                    visible={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                    transparent={false}
                >
                    <View>

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => { 
                                console.log('this text should close the modal'); 
                                console.log(this.state.selectedAlbum.album.image);
                                this.closeModal(item);
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                }}
                                source={{ uri: `${this.state.selectedAlbum.image}` }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </Modal>


            </View>;
    }

    renderAlbumList() {
        return (<FlatList
                    data={this.state.albums}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {                        
                        return (
                            this.singleAlbumRender(item)
                            //<Image
                            // style={{
                            //     width: 50,
                            //     height: 50,
                            // }}
                            //source={{ uri: `${pictureStuff}` }}
                        // />
                    );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
                    extraData={this.state.selectedAlbum}
        />);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.viewOne}>
                    {this.renderAlbumList()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        //backgroundColor: 'blue',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    viewOne: {
        // backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    singleAlbum: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    }
};

export default TestPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that works as I intended it.  I chose to keep everything in a single component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, 
        Image,
        TouchableOpacity,
        Modal,
        Alert,

} from 'react-native';

class TestPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            albums: [],
            modalIsOpen: false,
            selectedAlbum: null
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('component did mount');
        fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    albums: responseData,
                    isLoaded: true,
                });
            });
    }

    pictureOpen(item) {
        this.setState({ 
                modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen,
                selectedAlbum: item
            });
    }

    closeModal(item) {
        this.setState({
            modalIsOpen: false,
            selectedAlbum: { album: null }
        });
        console.log('here is the album data ', item.image);
    }
    singleAlbumRender(item) {        
        const pictureUrl = item.image;

        return this.state.selectedAlbum === null ?
            <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => { 
                        console.log('hey man no button pressed yet');
                        console.log('here is your state', this.state.selectedAlbum);
                        this.pictureOpen(item); 
                    }}
            >
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: `${pictureUrl}` }}
                    style={{
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                    }}

                />
                </TouchableOpacity>


            : 
            <View style={styles.singleAlbum}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => { 
                        console.log('hey man first');
                        console.log('here is your state', this.state.selectedAlbum);
                        this.pictureOpen(item); 
                    }}
                >
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: pictureUrl }}
                    style={{
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                    }}

                />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>;
    }

    renderAlbumList() {
        return (<FlatList
                    data={this.state.albums}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {                        
                        return (
                            this.singleAlbumRender(item)
                            //<Image
                            // style={{
                            //     width: 50,
                            //     height: 50,
                            // }}
                            //source={{ uri: `${pictureStuff}` }}
                        // />
                    );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
                    extraData={this.state.selectedAlbum}
        />);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.viewOne}>
                    {this.renderAlbumList()}
                </View>

                <Modal
                animationType="slide"    
                onRequestClose={() => {}}
                visible={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                transparent
                >
                    <View>

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => { 
                                const selectItem = this.state.selectedAlbum;
                                console.log('this text should close the modal'); 
                                this.closeModal(selectItem);
                            }}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                }}
                                source={this.state.selectedAlbum === null 
                                    ? null
                                    : { uri: this.state.selectedAlbum.image }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </Modal> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        //backgroundColor: 'blue',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    viewOne: {
        // backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    singleAlbum: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    }
};

export default TestPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

First i recommend you to create a new component for the album this makes the code more simple and clean, in this new component you use the Modal.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Modal, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class ImageModal extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           modalIsOpen: false
        }
    }
    handleModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen,
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View> 
                <View style={styles.singleAlbum}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={this.handleModal()}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={{ uri: `${this.state.selectedAlbum}` }}
                            style={{
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                            }}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide"    
                    onRequestClose={() => {}}
                    visible={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                    transparent={false}
                >
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={this.handleModal()}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200,
                                }}
                                source={{ uri: `${this.props.album.image}` }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});

export default ImageModal;
```

Then in the main you need to render this new component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ImageModal from './ImageModal';

class TestPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            albums: [],
            isLoad: false
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('component did mount');
        fetch('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    albums: responseData, isLoad: true
                });
            });
    }
    singleAlbumRender(item) {        
        return (
            <ImageModal album={item}/>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.viewOne}>
                    {this.state.isLoad ? 
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.albums}
                            renderItem={(item) => this.singleAlbumRender(item) }
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
                        /> : null }
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
});

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: I noticed in ImageModal.js the source for the Image is from this.state.selectedAlbum, but later within the actual Modal, the source for the image from this.props.album.image.  Why did you use two different sources.  Also, I was not able to get the pictures to render properly.